# How to use @RequestParam(value="foo") Map<MyEnum, String> in Spring Controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dictionary, enums, controller

I want to use some `Map<MyEnum, String>` as `@RequestParam` in my Spring Controller. For now I did the following:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    TESTA("TESTA"),
    TESTB("TESTB");

    String tag;

    // constructor MyEnum(String tag) and toString() method omitted
}

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void x(@RequestParam Map<MyEnum, String> test) {
    System.out.println(test);
    if(test != null) {
        System.out.println(test.size());
        for(Entry<MyEnum, String> e : test.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

This acts strange: I just get EVERY Parameter. So if I call the URL with `?FOO=BAR` it outputs `FOO : BAR`. So it definitely takes every String and not just the Strings defined in `MyEnum`.

So I thought about, why not name the param: `@RequestParam(value="foo") Map<MyEnum, String> test`. But then I just don't know how to pass the parameters, I always get `null`.

Or is there any other solution for this?

---

So if you have a look here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html

It says: *If the method parameter is `Map<String, String>` or `MultiValueMap<String, String>` and a parameter name is not specified [...]*. So it must be possible to use `value="foo"` and somehow set the values ;)

And: *If the method parameter type is `Map` and a request parameter name is specified, then the request parameter value is converted to a `Map` assuming an appropriate conversion strategy is available.* So where to specify a conversion strategy?

---

Now I've built a custom solution which works:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void x(@RequestParam Map<String, String> all) {
    Map<MyEnum, String> test = new HashMap<MyEnum, String>();
    for(Entry<String, String> e : all.entrySet()) {
        for(MyEnum m : MyEnum.values()) {
            if(m.toString().equals(e.getKey())) {
                test.put(m, e.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(test);
    if(test != null) {
        System.out.println(test.size());
        for(Entry<MyEnum, String> e : test.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Would be surely nicer if Spring could handle this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@RequestParam(value="foo") Map<MyEnum, String>
```

For Above to work:-
You have to pass values in below format
foo[MyTestA]= bar
foo[MyTestB]= bar2

Now to bind String such as "MyTestA","MyTestB" etc..to your MyEnum
You have to define a converter . Take a look a this [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch05s05.html)

Comment: It does, if you just have for example `@RequestParam("foo") MyEnum foo`. Seems just to be missing inside `Map`s.

Comment: I do not understand how this answer got 3 up votes. I am trying to bind request parameters to map in very similar way. And I don't need `Enum` there. I trying to get something just using `@RequestParam(value="foo") Map<String, String> foo`, but foo is always null. My url looks like `/my-service?foo[1]=2&foor[10]=20` as suggested in this answer.