# Spring/Jackson RequestParam with HashMap from Angular

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Trying to understand what is wrong with the sending of a Hashmap of values.

Client-side (Angular)

```js
var params = {
    year: reportYear,
    reportAgg: {
        "interest": "Java",
        "domain": "JavaCodeGeeks.com"
    }
};

return $http.post('test/' + pathVariable1 + '/',
    $.param(params), {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });
```

Server-Side (Spring/Jackson)

```
@RequestMapping(value = RqMapping, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity sendReports(
    final @PathVariable(value = "pathVariable1") String organizationId,
    final @RequestParam(value = "year", required = true) int requestedYear,
    final @RequestParam(value = "reportAgg", required = false) Map<String, String> reportAgg,
    final HttpServletRequest request) {
```

In the `request.getParametersMap` its possible to see the expected `reportAgg[interest]` and `reportAgg[domain]` but still i get a null value for `reportAgg` in the mapping.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765234/how-to-use-requestparamvalue-foo-mapmyenum-string-in-spring-controller - i tried to do it as this SO question.

Comment: How does your http request look ? do you have an example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JackSon's ObjectMapper to convert into HashMap

```
 @RequestMapping(value = RqMapping, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity sendReports(
        final @PathVariable(value = "pathVariable1") String organizationId,
        final @RequestParam(value = "year", required = true) int requestedYear,
        final @RequestParam(value = "reportAgg", required = false) String reportAgg,
        final HttpServletRequest request) {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                String json = reportAgg;

                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // convert JSON string to Map
                map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});

                System.out.println(map ); // out put as HashMap<String, String>

}// end of sendReports()
```